# Why does curl time out locally?

Tags: curl, timeout

The site runs on Ubuntu 20.04 / Apache 2.4.41. We receive cUrl error 28 (connection timeout) in local Wordpress and cli. The command works as expected when run from my home pc.

From home pc:

c:\Program Files\curl-8.4.0_7-win64-mingw\bin>
`curl -I https://crmspace.de:443`

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 28 Nov 2023 13:22:55 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu)
Last-Modified: Tue, 28 Nov 2023 10:39:06 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8 [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Thu4l.jpg)

From local machine:

curl: (28) Failed to connect to crmspace.de port 443: Connection timed out [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v2bO4.jpg)

Comment: Are you trying to reach the [external IP address of your router](https://serverfault.com/questions/380479/networking-access-to-external-ip-from-within-that-network/380482)?

Comment: yes, it's our external / public IP address, registered in DNS with "crmspace.de"

Comment: Because it was designed to work with sensible websites, not wordpress. `man curl` will tell you how to set a longer timeout if that really is the cause of the issue (could also be DNS, routing or firewall issues).

Comment: symcbean, when subscribing to this forum I understood that we should avoid posting opinions here... :D

Comment: Hairpin NAT often doesn't work. Split-brain DNS is a thing.

Comment: Can you do `ping -a crmspace.de` from the Ubuntu server. And is your dns Resolver correct in resolv.conf. You might also be able to run curl verbose with `curl -v -i crmspace.de `to get more debug info

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been solved, based on the information provided by @Gerald Schneider (by setting up "hairpin routing" / NAT Reflection on our pfSense firewall).
Thank you.